# Chat app - using Swift3, Alamofire, mySQL, php API

Tags: swift3, chat, alamofire

Can someone help me? Swift newbie here.
I need to develop chatting function in my app.. so I use ‘chatto’ but I do not understand this library.
My DB is mySQL and communicate using Alamofire. I have a php API that communicates with mySQL. This includes user’s chat information.

If someone ever used Chatto or is there a better way to create a chat app?
( chatto link : https://github.com/badoo/Chatto )

## 1. if using Chatto

( chatto essue : https://github.com/badoo/Chatto/issues/349 )
I didn't understant how to using it.. I've followed the ChattoApp example, but I do not understand how FakeDataSource, FakeMessageFactory, etc. work.

I using Swift3, Alamofire and mySQL.

I did

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatSegue", sender: self) }
```

so I connect ChatViewController with TableView. so if I select tableCell, view Chatto interface.

and.. I can't printed any text. I didn't understand https://github.com/badoo/Chatto/wiki/Data-source . if I have 3 array

```
var userName = [String?]()
var messages = [String?]()
var updated_at = [String?]()
```

how to insert these items to datasource? or What I have to do to use Chatto fot this case?

I did not understand it, but I pasted the example code in a way that erased the error message..
[image]

## 2. If there is a better way.

Please let me know something! I don't know what I have to do.

Thank you

Comment: have you implemented this...can you tell how it can be done.?

Comment: I'm late! At that time, I implemented only chat using firebase, and separated chat DB from mysql.